# Implementación recursiva de QuickSort, no ordena el array

Tags: python, ordenamiento, python-2.x, quicksort

Tengo la siguiente implementación del algoritmo de ordenamiento QuickSort:

```
def quicksort(arreglo,izq,der):
    i=izq
    j=der
    piv=arreglo[(izq + der)/2]

    while( i <= j ):
        while arreglo[i]<piv and j<=der:
            i=i+1
        while piv<arreglo[j] and j>izq:
            j=j-1
        if i<=j:
            aux = arreglo[i]; 
            arreglo[i] = arreglo[j]; 
            arreglo[j] = aux;
            i=i+1;  
            j=j-1;

        if izq < j:
          quicksort( arreglo, izq, j );
    if i < der:
        quicksort( arreglo, i, der );

def imprimeLista(arreglo,tam):
    for i in range(0,tam): print arreglo[i],



def leeLista():
    arreglo=[]
    a=int(raw_input("Ingresa el tamano del arreglo: "))

    for i in range(0,a):
     #   arreglo.append(int(raw_input("Ingresa los valores %d : " % i)))

     arch = open('or.txt', 'r')

     for linea in arch:
        arreglo.append(linea.strip())

     arch.close()    

    pos=int(raw_input("Selecciona el pivote: "))
    return arreglo

A=leeLista()
tiempo_inicial = time()
quicksort(A,0,len(A)-1)
tiempo_final = time()
tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial
print'El tiempo de ejecucion fue ::', tiempo_ejecucion
imprimeLista(A,len(A))
```

El problema es que solo muestra el arreglo tal cual sale del archivo:

> 2,24,3,26,21,1, 4, 5, 29,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 30,16, 17,
>   18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25,  27, 28,11 2,24,3,26,21,1, 4, 5, 29,6, 7, 8,
>   9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 30,16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25,  27, 28,11
>   2,24,3,26,21,1, 4, 5, 29,6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 30,16, 17,
>   18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25,  27, 28,11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu implementación de quicksort funciona ordenado la lista 'in-place', sin usar memoria adicional, ese no es el problema.

Tienes algunos errores:

- Deberias hacer casting a `int` al cargar los datos en la lista:

  ```
  arreglo.append(int(linea.strip())
  ```

  De lo contrario, `quicksort` ordenará una lista de cadenas (orden lexicográfico) y no una de enteros.
- Hay errores de identación en la función `leerLista`, además hay dos `input` que no usas para nada. Debería ser algo así:

  ```
  def leeLista():
      arreglo=[]
      arch = open('or.txt', 'r')

      for linea in arch:
          arreglo.append(int(linea.strip()))

      arch.close()    
      return arreglo
  ```
- No importas `time`

Por otro lado hay cosas que se pueden mejorar para hacer el código más efiiente y 'pythónico':

- No uses el índices para imprimir la lista, esto es ineficiente. En su lugar itera sobre la lista con el for:

  ```
  def imprimeLista(arreglo):
      for n in arreglo:
          print n
  ```
- El método `append` de las listas es lento, sería mucho más simple y eficiente usar compresión de listas para generar la lista a partir del txt:

  ```
  def leeLista():
      with open('quicksort_datos.txt', 'r') as f:
          return [int(linea.strip()) for linea in f]
  ```

El código podría quedar así:

```
from time import time



def quick_sort(arreglo, izq, der):
    i = izq
    j = der
    piv = arreglo[(izq + der) // 2]

    while i <= j:
        while arreglo[i] < piv and j <= der:
            i += 1
        while piv < arreglo[j] and j > izq:
            j -= 1

        if i <= j:
            arreglo[i], arreglo[j] = arreglo[j], arreglo[i]
            i += 1
            j -= 1

        if izq < j:
          quick_sort(arreglo, izq, j)

    if i < der:
        quick_sort(arreglo, i, der)

def imprimir_lista(arreglo):
    for n in arreglo:
        print(n)

def leer_lista(ruta):
    with open(ruta, 'r') as f:
        return [int(linea.strip()) for linea in f]

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    a = leer_lista('quicksort_datos.txt')
    tiempo_inicial = time()
    quick_sort(a, 0, len(a)-1)
    tiempo_final = time()
    tiempo_ejecucion = tiempo_final - tiempo_inicial
    print('El tiempo de ejecucion fue de {} segundos.'.format(tiempo_ejecucion))
    imprimir_lista(a)
```

Algo muy importante y que no has aclarado es cómo está estructurado tu txt. El código que usas es para leer archivos de la forma:

> 2
>   24
>   3
>   26
>   21
>   1
>   ...

Es decir, **cada elemento está en una línea diferente**.

---

Decir que aunque tu implementación de QuickSort es correcta, es bastante ineficiente, la verdadera clave del algoritmo está en hacer la partición del array en torno al pivote lo más eficiente posible. Otra posible implementación puede ser:

```
def quick_sort_2(array, left, right):
    '''Quick Sort recursiva con partición, ordenamiento in-place'''
    if right <= left:
        return None

    new_right = left
    new_left = right
    idx = left + 1
    pivot = array[left]

    # Particion
    while idx <= new_left:
        if array[idx] < pivot:
            array[new_right], array[idx] = array[idx], array[new_right]
            new_right += 1
            idx += 1
        elif array[idx] > pivot:
            array[new_left], array[idx] = array[idx], array[new_left]
            new_left -= 1
        else:
            idx += 1

    quick_sort_2(array, left, new_right - 1)
    quick_sort_2(array, new_left + 1, right)
```

Un pequeño test con un array aleatorio de 4000 enteros:

> ```
> In [17]: array = [random.randint(-1000, 1000) for _ in range(4000)]
>          array2 = array.copy()
> In [18]: array
> Out[18]: [930,
>           17,
>           378,
>           -799,
>           -853,
>           -686,
>           -768,
> In [19]: %time quick_sort(array, 0, len(array)-1)
>          CPU times: user 1min 34s, sys: 13.3 ms, total: 1min 34s
>          Wall time: 1min 34s
>
> In [20]: %time quick_sort_2(array2, 0, len(array2)-1)
>          CPU times: user 11.3 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 11.3 ms
>          Wall time: 10.7 ms
>
> In [21]: array
> Out[21]: [-1000,
>           -1000,
>           -1000,
>           -999,
>           -998,
> `         -997,
>           -997,
>           -996,
>           ...]
>
> In [22]: array == array2
> Out[22]: True
> ```

Pasamos de un minuto y medio a unos 10 milisegundos....

> **Importante**: El algoritmo anterior es un claro ejemplo de recursión y del paradigma "divide y vencerás". No obstante, la recursión tiene como límite el tamaño de la pila. Python por defecto tiene un límite de 1000 llamadas recursivas, esto es así para proteger la pila de C ya que su desbordamiento implica la terminación del propio intérprete. Esto hace que el algoritmo no sea adecuado para iterables muy extensos (aunque depende de los elementos y el orden de partida ya que esto determina el número de particiones)

---

**Edición**:

En relación a algunos comentarios sobre que el código original no es compatible con Python 3, he editado el código para que si lo sea. El problema estaba en la línea:

```
piv = arreglo[(izq + der) / 2]
```

La causa es que en Python 2 el tipo del resultado de la división depende del de los operandos. Si ambos son enteros se retorna un entero (división entera), si alguno es un float se retorna un float (división real). En Python 3 el operador `/` siempre retorna un float con la división real. Como no está permitido usar float para indexar tenemos un error, la solución es simplemente usar el operador de la división entera `//`:

```
piv = arreglo[(izq + der) // 2]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por las observaciones me sirvieron de mucha ayuda. y la forma en que leo el archivo es como lo muestras en la primera forma

Comment: Hola @Agon, es decir, ¿los numeros están separados por un espacio y no por un salto de línea?. Si es así puedo editar la respuesta acorede a esto. Saludos.

Comment: es por salto de linea

Comment: Ok, es que los comentarios no admiten los saltos de linea... XD. Entoces nada, lo dejo tal y como está. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias :D

Comment: Con respecto al mismo código (el final y mejorado) mostrado,
estoy utilizando Python 3.0.6
y al compilar y ejecutar me arroja errores de enteros en lineas donde se define el "piv" (6) y linea al final donde se arroja "quicksort(A, 0, len(A)-1)" (55).
Hay algún problema con la versión o de código?? Saludos