# Problema de recursión infinita en el algoritmo de quicksort en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ordenamiento, quicksort

Mi código tiene un problema muy grande de recursividad infinita en la función `quicksort` linea 15.
Ya mire todas las posibilidades por las cuales no retorna y no le veo alguna.

Aquí está:

```
def comprobarOrdenado(array):
    for i in range(1,len(array)):
        if array[i-1] > array[i]:
            return False #Arreglo desordenado
    return True #Arreglo ordenado   

def quicksort(array):
    ordenado = [] #Array posiblemente ordenado
    if(len(array) <= 1): #Array sin necesidad de ordenar
        return array
    pivote = len(array)//2

    #Partir mayores y menores elementos que el pivote
    mayores = menores = [] 
    for i in range(len(array)):    
        if(i==pivote):
            continue
        if(array[i] >= array[pivote]):
            mayores.append(array[i])
        else:
            menores.append(array[i])        

    #Unir particiones
    menores.append(array[pivote])
    ordenado = menores + mayores #Se concatenan los arrays
    if(comprobarOrdenado(ordenado) == False):
        ordenado = quicksort(ordenado)  
    return ordenado 

arregloDesordenado = [3,4,-2,7,5,1]
print(quicksort(arregloDesordenado))
```

Comment: No he ejecutado tu código. Pero, al leerlo me parece que entras en loop infinito porque a partir de la segunda entrada a quicksort() el array que devuelves no cambia y se mantiene desordenado. Hay un fallo en la implementación del algoritmo.

Comment: En esta respuesta de @FJSevilla [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67333/91033] se ilustra una implementación correcta. Compara con tu código.

Comment: La idea del *quicksort* es ordenar las dos mitades antes de concatenarlas, no después.

Comment: Aparte del error comentado por @ChemaCortes `mayores = menores = []` es una mala idea... En Python las variables son solo nombres que están asociados a un objeto determinado, lo que hace la linea anterior es crear una nueva lista vacía y asociar tanto el nombre `mayores` como `menores` a ella. Ambos identificadores apuntan al mismo objeto `list`.. luego realizas el `.append`. siempre a la misma lista independientemente de si elemento es mayor o menor al pivote.  Además tu lista aparte de no ordenarse se duplica entre llamadas recursivas por la misma razón...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### :: OFFTOPIC ::

El algoritmo `quicksort` es conocido por ordenar la secuencia en el mismo sitio donde se almacena, no neceistando más memoria.

En tu implementación, estás troceando la lista y almacenándolas en trozos nuevos. Más que una implementación del `quicksort` se asemeja a una variante de *programación funcional* donde la lista original no se vería modificada.

Por dar una idea, pongo una solución *funcional* para que se vea cómo debería funcionar. Se podría optimizar más, aunque la idea es que se entienda:

```
def quicksort(array):

    if (len(array) <= 1):
        return array

    pivot = array[len(array) // 2]

    lt = [i for i in array if i < pivot]
    eq = [pivot] * array.count(pivot)
    gt = [i for i in array if i > pivot]

    return quicksort(lt) + eq + quicksort(gt)
```

Para comprobar que está ordenada, también se podría hacer una versión más *funcional*:

```
def check_sorting(array):
    return (True if len(array) <= 1
            else all(i <= j for (i, j) in zip(array, array[1:])))
```